# Where is the C# google (Calendar) api documentation?

Tags: c#, google-api-client, google-authentication, google-api-dotnet-client

Where is the C# Google API documentation?

Where are the sample codes?

These are obsolete.

https://developers.google.com/gdata/client-cs
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples#hg/Calendar.VB.ConsoleApp

The web full of unanswered similar questions.

Comment: Answers are for questions, not rants.

Answer (score 7):

OK...

I'll start with saying that the GData library is old and my recommendation is to work with Google APIs library for .NET. this library is currently maintained and we just release a new version of it two weeks ago. More details are available here:

1. The code of the core library (which is open source) is available in our repository - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/.
2. All the samples are available in https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/?repo=samples
3. Our developer guide pages contains a lot for information about how to use [OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth), [Media upload](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_upload) and [Media Download](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/media_download), etc. BUT we don't have a full documentation of the API available online. I just opened a new issue in our issue tracker - https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/issues/detail?id=410. Feel free to add more content to it.
4. All the Google.Apis generated libraries (for Calendar, YouTube, Drive, Storage, etc.) are available using NuGet. You can find all our packages here https://www.nuget.org/packages?q=google.apis&prerelease=true&sortOrder=relevance. You can also find the code that generates them in our repository.

What else?

UPDATE:
The calendar API .NET docs are available in https://google-api-client-libraries.appspot.com/documentation/calendar/v3/csharp/1.8.0-rc/annotated.html.

Comment: what an appropriate response for a bad a question.

Comment: Just one comment. Compared to the old Calendar samples. The new 'Calendar VB Console App' is a bit poor....